# SharePoint 2013 with .net framework 4.6.1

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, .net

I am facing a requirement to install an external program on SharePoint environment. the program requires `.net framework 4.6.1`.

Is there a problem in installing `.net framework 4.6.1` on SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be aware of the SharePoint 2013 SP1 does support installing .Net 4.6 onto an existing SharePoint 2013 farm server.

But you may face an issue if you try to install SharePoint 2013 on .NET framework 4.6 . and this issue is now solved as mentioned at [SharePoint 2013 installer now supports .NET Framework 4.6 and above](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/09/14/sharepoint-2013-installer-now-supports-net-framework-4-6-and-above/)

For more details check [SharePoint 2013 and .NET framework 4.6](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2015/08/11/sharepoint-2013-and-net-framework-4-6/)

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

What about installing .Net 4.6 on the SharePoint database servers? .Net 4.6 is required as a part of installation for Power BI report server.